# How do I develop a QGIS Data Provider?

Tags: qgis

I want to develop a data provider for QGIS, but I cannot find any documentation on how to. I can see that Python plugins are popular, but from the repository it looks like data providers are written in C++ (which I am perfectly fine with) and that they're somewhat dynamically loaded in.

Can anyone point me to documentation on how to do this? Or is my only choice to join their mailing list and ask a "how to get started" question there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked on the developer mailinglist. Although it's a while ago I suppose the question (and the answers) are still valid:
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2010-June/010314.html

I'm not aware of any documentation since writing a new provider has probably been done mostly by core developers. So I guess there's unfortunatley no other choice than to browse through the repository of existing providers and start reading code: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/src/providers